# Numpy, convert for loop to numpy array/vector operations

Tags: python, numpy, classification, logistic-regression

I want to implement Logistic Regression with crossentropy loss using this formula for loss function and the gradient of it.

[the image of loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvLcf.png)

[the image of the gradient of the loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xaYZ.png)

This is my code in python. I want to make this code to operate without a for loop and more like vector or array type operations.

```
w = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
hasses = []

for i in range(X.shape[0]):
    soo = np.dot(y, X)
    print(soo)
    print(soo.shape)
    mac = np.dot(y[i], w.T, X[i])
    #print(mac)
    print(mac.shape)
    mac = 1 + np.exp(mac)
    #print(mac)
    print(mac.shape)
    has = soo / mac
    #print(has)
    print(has.shape)
    hasses.append(has)
    sdf

hasses = np.array(hasses)
print(hasses)
print(hasses.shape)
res = np.sum(hasses)
print(res)
print(res.shape)
res /= X.shape[0]
print(res)
print(res.shape)
```

The dataset is Titanic dataset. I have 3 features for X, plus one feature for bias (which contains only 1 value) and for labels, only +1 and -1.

Thanks.

Comment: The whole solution is nicely documented in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8

Comment: I'm implementing Logistic Regression from scratch, not using a package. But, thanks. @FlorinC.